# Currency comapre not working as expected in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this angularjs condition in HTML

```
<td>    
    <div style="color:red" ng-if="s.paid_amount == 0">
        Open
    </div>
    <div style="color:#D5DC07" ng-if="s.paid_amount > 0 && s.paid_amount < s.bill_amount">
        Semi Closed
    </div>
    <div style="color:#02FC1B" ng-if="s.paid_amount == s.bill_amount">
        Closed
    </div>
<td>
```

This is the response from query.

[image]

so ideally it should print semiclosed for both records. But its not printing any of 3 condition.

Is there any different way to compare currency in angular?

Comment: What about types of `paid_amount` and `bill_amount`?

Comment: @SatanDmytro they are decimal(10, 2) in mysql.

Comment: And inside controller it's number too?

Comment: @SatanDmytro Inside controller i am not saving them. looping directly. after http call saving the data in suppliers(scope variable) and then <tr ng-repeat="s in suppliers">

Comment: Have you checked that the content of s object is right? Can you show a console.log of it?

Comment: I reverified contents. its correct. {bill_id: "hhf-988", date: "2017-04-11", supplier_id: "1", bill_amount: "2500.00", paid_amount: "433.00", …}
1
:
{bill_id: "JHK-1232", date: "2017-04-10", supplier_id: "1", bill_amount: "15000.00", paid_amount: "5000.00", …}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison is failing because the original data is a String rather than being a number. You need to convert the data to Number first. I checked your data by running the following and it does indeed return true.

`Number(s.paid_amount) > 0 && Number(s.paid_amount) < Number(s.bill_amount)`

Now, you can convert the data to a number in two ways. The preferred method would be inside the controller. You can do the following on the dataset.

```
data = data.map(function (o) {
            o.paid_amount = Number(o.paid_amount);
            o.bill_amount = Number(o.bill_amount);
            return o;
        });
```

Or, the other way would be to call a function from the controller inside your ng-repeat block.

**CONTROLLER :**

```
[$scope/vm].toNumber = function (num) {
        return Number(num);
    }
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<td>    
<div style="color:red" ng-if="toNumber(s.paid_amount) == 0">
    Open
</div>
<div style="color:#D5DC07" ng-if="toNumber(s.paid_amount) > 0 && toNumber(s.paid_amount) < toNumber(s.bill_amount)">
    Semi Closed
</div>
<div style="color:#02FC1B" ng-if="toNumber(s.paid_amount == toNumber(s.bill_amount)">
    Closed
</div>
```

Off course, there might be better ways to achieve the conversion. But this is the gist of what needs to be done.